# How to Dynamically load images in Listview and Text with Facebook like feature?

Tags: listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I would like to ask help on how to deal with loading text and image in listview simultaneously. I get the data from database(Text/Message and Image(url of the image)) and I want to load them in a listview, a concept like in facebook where every comment is being loaded simultaneously and independently from each other.

so far I have this concept:

Created Adapter and inside it put an Asynctask. Btw, the data that being pass to the adapter are already extracted from database through Jsonparsing.

new GetPictureAsync(imgview).execute("sample url");

//this line is coded inside getview of the adapter. i pass a imgview in my GetPictureAsync class and pass the result bitmap to this view.

Problem is that, the Adapter is loading the data once, it means that it is waiting for the last object or value before displaying it in the listview.

I would really appreciate your inputs. You can give theory or correct way on how to approach this type of scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for this by using Google's library called [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/). It has a class NetworkImageView that would make the loading of image in a separate thread.

// If you are using NetworkImageView
imgNetWorkView.setImageUrl(Const.URL_IMAGE, imageLoader);